# Android TabLayout and using LoaderCallbacks to populate a Fragment

Tags: java, android

So I'm working on an assignment where I have to create a TabLayout representing different categories of news, where the news is retrieved using the Bing search API and the JSON is parsed and used to populate the ListView in the three Fragments that make up the TabLayout. I'm also using a ViewPager.

My issue is that for some reason, the content of all three Fragments is the same... same article results. Why is this? I'm using Loader IDs, and the loader is initialized in the onActivityCreated() method. Is there a way I can load the articles relevant to the current Fragment when the user swipes over to that tab?

Here are the relevant methods of my Fragments. They're almost identical in each Fragment, with the exception of the LOADER_ID and CATEGORY_NAME values.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // Get a reference to the ConnectivityManager to check state of network connectivity
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
            getContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    // Get details on the currently active default data network
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    // If there is a network connection, fetch data
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        // Get a reference to the LoaderManager, in order to interact with loaders.
        LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();

        // Initialize the loader. Pass in the int ID constant defined above and pass in null for
        // the bundle. Pass in this activity for the LoaderCallbacks parameter (which is valid
        // because this activity implements the LoaderCallbacks interface).
        loaderManager.initLoader(WorldFragment.LOADER_ID, null, this);
    } else {
        // Otherwise, display error
        // First, hide loading indicator so error message will be visible
        View loadingIndicator = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
        loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // Update empty state with no connection error message
        mEmptyStateTextView.setText(R.string.no_internet_connection);
    }
}

@Override
public Loader<List<Article>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new ArticleLoader(this.getContext(), WorldFragment.CATEGORY_NAME);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Article>> loader, List<Article> articles) {
    // Hide loading indicator because the data has been loaded
    View loadingIndicator = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
    loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    // Set empty state text to display "No articles found."
    mEmptyStateTextView.setText(R.string.no_articles);

    // Clear the adapter of previous earthquake data
    adapter.clear();

    // If there is a valid list of {@link Earthquake}s, then add them to the adapter's
    // data set. This will trigger the ListView to update.
    if (articles != null && !articles.isEmpty()) {
        adapter.addAll(articles);
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<Article>> loader) {
    adapter.clear();
}
```

And here is the source for my ArticleLoader class. The "fetchArticleData" call is what retrieves the Article objects by parsing the JSON into Article objects.

```
public class ArticleLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<Article>> {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = ArticleLoader.class.getName();

    private String category;

    public ArticleLoader(Context context, String category) {
        super(context);
        this.category = category;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        forceLoad();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Article> loadInBackground() {
        if (category == null) {
            return null;
        }

        // Perform the network request, parse the response, and extract a list of earthquakes.
        List<Article> articles = QueryUtils.fetchArticleData(category);
        return articles;
    }
}
```

As per request, here is the QueryUtils class.

```
public class QueryUtils {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = QueryUtils.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String REQUEST_BASE_URL = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/news/";
    private static final String API_KEY = "redacted";

    /**
     * Create a private constructor because no one should ever create a {@link QueryUtils} object.
     * This class is only meant to hold static variables and methods, which can be accessed
     * directly from the class name QueryUtils (and an object instance of QueryUtils is not needed).
     */
    private QueryUtils() {
    }

    /**
     * Query the USGS dataset and return a list of {@link Article} objects.
     */
    public static List<Article> fetchArticleData(String category) {
        // Create URL object
        HttpURLConnection conn = createUrlConnection(category);

        // Perform HTTP request to the URL and receive a JSON response back
        String jsonResponse = null;
        try {
            jsonResponse = makeHttpRequest(conn);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem making the HTTP request.", e);
        }

        // Extract relevant fields from the JSON response and create a list of {@link Article}s
        List<Article> articles = extractFeatureFromJson(jsonResponse);

        // Return the list of {@link Article}s
        return articles;
    }

    /**
     * Returns new URL object from the given string URL.
     */
    private static HttpURLConnection createUrlConnection(String category) {
        URL url = null;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(QueryUtils.REQUEST_BASE_URL);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Category", category);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", QueryUtils.API_KEY);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem building the URL connection ", e);
        }
        return conn;
    }

    /**
     * Make an HTTP request to the given URL and return a String as the response.
     */
    private static String makeHttpRequest(HttpURLConnection conn) throws IOException {
        String jsonResponse = "";

        // If the URL is null, then return early.
        if (conn == null) {
            return jsonResponse;
        }

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            conn.connect();

            // If the request was successful (response code 200),
            // then read the input stream and parse the response.
            if (conn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
                jsonResponse = readFromStream(inputStream);
            } else {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error response code: " + conn.getResponseCode());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem retrieving the article JSON results.", e);
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
            if (inputStream != null) {
                // Closing the input stream could throw an IOException, which is why
                // the makeHttpRequest(URL url) method signature specifies than an IOException
                // could be thrown.
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
        return jsonResponse;
    }

    /**
     * Convert the {@link InputStream} into a String which contains the
     * whole JSON response from the server.
     */
    private static String readFromStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        if (inputStream != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                output.append(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
        }
        return output.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Return a list of {@link Article} objects that has been built up from
     * parsing the given JSON response.
     */
    private static List<Article> extractFeatureFromJson(String articleJSON) {
        // If the JSON string is empty or null, then return early.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(articleJSON)) {
            return null;
        }

        // Create an empty ArrayList that we can start adding articles to
        List<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>();

        // Try to parse the JSON response string. If there's a problem with the way the JSON
        // is formatted, a JSONException exception object will be thrown.
        // Catch the exception so the app doesn't crash, and print the error message to the logs.
        try {
            // Create a JSONObject from the JSON response string
            JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(articleJSON);

            // Extract the JSONArray associated with the key called "features",
            // which represents a list of features (or articles).
            JSONArray articleArray = baseJsonResponse.getJSONArray("value");

            // For each article in the articleArray, create an {@link Article} object
            for (int i = 0; i < articleArray.length(); i++) {

                // Get a single article at position i within the list of articles
                JSONObject currentArticle = articleArray.getJSONObject(i);

                // Extract the value for the key called "name"
                String articleName = currentArticle.getString("name");

                // Extract the value for the key called "url"
                String articleSource = currentArticle.getString("url");

                // Extract the value for the key called "image"
                JSONObject imageObject = currentArticle.getJSONObject("image");
                String imageSource = imageObject.getJSONObject("thumbnail").getString("contentUrl");

                // Create a new {@link Article} object with the name, url, and image
                // from the JSON response.
                Article article = new Article(articleName, articleSource, imageSource);

                // Add the new {@link Article} to the list of articles.
                articles.add(article);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // If an error is thrown when executing any of the above statements in the "try" block,
            // catch the exception here, so the app doesn't crash. Print a log message
            // with the message from the exception.
            Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing the article JSON results", e);
        }

        // Return the list of articles
        return articles;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your `QueryUtils.fetchArticleData()` method is working as expected? Are you sure your `PagerAdapter` is actually returning the three different `Fragment`s?

Comment: The TabLayout and Fragment classes were pretty much copy-pasted from a previous assignment. I know those work. And I know the QueryUtils method works because the data is being displayed as expected. However, the only reason for it to display the same articles in all three tabs is if they're all accessing the same Loader (the same articles) and it's not being reloaded when I switch tabs. The method takes a category as an argument and uses that category as a requestProperty when requesting the data through the API.

Comment: "...the data is being displayed as expected." - Unless I'm misreading the question, it doesn't sound like that's true. I'm reading it as, all 3 `Fragment`s are showing the same dataset. Are you sure `QueryUtils` is actually returning the correct dataset for a given category? You should do a little debugging to see exactly what is getting duplicated; i.e., is it 3 of the same `Fragment`, or 3 of the same dataset from `QueryUtils`, etc. The code you've posted looks OK.

Comment: I've added the QueryUtils class to my original post.

Comment: Yeah, wasn't really a request for the class. More of a suggestion to debug. :-) Anyhoo, what is it that your `Fragment`s are showing? Is it the sum total of all of the articles from all categories, or is it just the articles from one? If just one, which one? First loaded, or last? Also, do your `Fragment`s happen to all extend a common base class?

Comment: All Fragments show the same articles, and on a cursory glance, it seems that there are articles from all of the categories, even ones I didn't include among my Fragments. Perhaps the requestProperty is wrong? I could manually add the category text at the end of the URL, but I'm not sure if that would work. I'll try and let you know.

Comment: That seems to have been the problem. Thanks! I'm not sure why setting it as a requestProperty didn't work, though.